# How to prove that there are finitely many $n$ such that $f(1+1/n) = \frac{1}{n+1}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be analytical. How does one prove that there are finitely many positive $n$ such that $f(1+1/n) = \frac{1}{n+1}$ ? A hint is given: think of the expression $\frac{z-1}{z}$.

I think this is a pretty hard homework assignment. Here's what I tried so far: Let $g(z) = \frac{z-1}{z} $ . Then $g(1 + 1/n) = \frac{1 + 1/n - 1}{ 1 + 1/n} = \frac{1/n}{1+1/n} = \frac{1}{n+1} $. So the given hint is probably indeed useful, but I'm not sure yet how.

Another thing I tried to use to obtain the solution was the given fact that $f$ is analytical. Let $f = g$. Then $f(z) = f(x+iy) = \frac{ x + iy - 1}{x+iy} = \frac{x+iy-1}{x+iy} \cdot \frac{x-iy}{x-iy} = \frac{x^2 - 2 i x y + y^2 + iy}{x^2 + y^2} = 1 + i \frac{y(1-2x)}{x^2 + y^2} $ . Now I have written $f$ in the form $ f = u + i v$, with $u,v$ being real-valued functions. So now we can use the Cauchy-Riemann Integral formulas: $ \frac{d}{dx} 1 = 0 = \frac{d}{dy} \frac{ y(1-2x) }{x^2+y^2} \implies \frac{y(1-2x)}{x^2+y^2} = c $. The other formula yields a similar result.

But now what? I still have no idea how to prove that there are finitely many positive $n$ such that the aforementioned equality holds. Should I use any of the results I already obtained? If so, how? If not, do you know how to prove this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

Let $g(z)=f(z)-\frac{z-1}{z}$.

If $f(1+1/n) = \frac{1}{n+1}$ then

$$g(1+1/n) = 0 \,.$$

If there are infinitely many such $n$ then they forma  sequence which converges to $1$. What can you say then about $g$?

Also, why is $f(z)=\frac{z-1}{z}$ not possible?

Comment: Thank you, N.S. . I tried to work out the hints you have given me, but I still don't really know how to apply them to the problem. Could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: @MaxMuller What do you know about the points where an Analytic function is zero?

Comment: ehm, that these points are the roots of the analytic function?

Comment: @MaxMuller One of the first theorems you probably learned about analytic functions sais that if the zeroes of analytic functions have an accumulation point, then ......

Comment: Hmm I don't think we covered this theorem in class.. I think I know to which theorem you're refering to, though. From the wikipedia article "Analytic function", in the "properties of analytic function" - section: A similar but weaker statement holds for analytic functions. If the set of zeros of an analytic function $ƒ$ has an accumulation point inside its domain, then ƒ is zero everywhere on the connected component containing the accumulation point. In other words, if $(r_n)$ is a sequence of distinct numbers such that $ƒ(r_n) = 0 $ for all $n$ and this sequence converges to a point $r$ in...

Comment: in the domain of $D$, then $ƒ$ is identically zero on the connected component of $D$ containing $r$.

Comment: @MaxMuller  Well apply that theorem for the infinitely many $n$ for which $g(1+\frac{1}{n})=0$. That proves that $G=0$ ;)

Comment: Jep! Thanks a lot. (I guess you meant to say $g=0$, no?) But then we have $f(z) = \frac{z-1}{z}$. According to you, this isn't possible. I'll try to figure out why it isn't possible.

Comment: @MaxMuller Exactly, it means that $g=0$ thus $f(z)=\frac{z-1}{z}$... But $f$ is analytic, which is a contradiction, because $\frac{z-1}{z}$ is not analytic at....

Comment: I guess it's not analytic at $z=0$.

Comment: @maxmuller Yup. So you start assuming by contradiction that there are infinitely many $n$ and that is the contradiction you get, $f=\frac{z-1}{z}$ and $f$ is analytic at $z=0$....

Comment: Yes, I understand know :-) . Thanks a lot for all your additional explanatory comments!